# Regex not working for some dates

Tags: ruby, regex, date

I'm matching dates via regex. It's working pretty well for some but for others it's simply not working but I don't understand why.

I'm doing this in Ruby for the German language:

```
def extract_dates
  months = ["Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]
  days = ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"]
  self.content.scan(/([0-9]{1,2}\.\s?[#{months.join("|")}]\s?[0-9]{4})/)
end
```

I tested it on the text of: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkunabel, which I randomly selected. It returns:

```
=> ["18. Juli 1471", "11. Februar 1486", "14. August 1473", "1. Januar 1501", "8. Januar 2008", "23. Mai 2006"]
```

And the matches are correct but it leaves out `"31. Dezember 1500"` which, for my purposes should be matched but isn't. Why does it not match `"31. Dezember 1500"`?

Comment: If you're going to be scraping Wikipedia, use their [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), or risk being banned. It's the friendly way to roll.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have parentheses () around the months, not brackets [].

```
/([0-9]{1,2}\.\s?(#{months.join("|")})\s?[0-9]{4})/
```

If it works for other dates it's probably because the date is written as `31.&nbsp;Dezember&nbsp;1500` in the html source.

**Update:**

To avoid returning the month in each match, just use a non-capturing group `(?: )`

But your original regex, if it worked at all, should also have returned each result in a subarray, because of the outer set of parentheses.

```
content = "31. Dezember 1500 and 8. Januar 2008"
months = ["Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]

# Your original expression
content.scan /([0-9]{1,2}\.\s?[#{months.join("|")}]\s?[0-9]{4})/
# => []

# With a non-capturing group instead of []
content.scan /([0-9]{1,2}\.\s?(?:#{months.join("|")})\s?[0-9]{4})/
# => [["31. Dezember 1500"], ["8. Januar 2008"]]

# Without the outer parentheses
content.scan /[0-9]{1,2}\.\s?(?:#{months.join("|")})\s?[0-9]{4}/
# => ["31. Dezember 1500", "8. Januar 2008"]
```

I'm also on 1.9.3 so that is not an issue.

Comment: Swithcing form [] to () didnt change anything to the result just to the way the results are returned. Now each result is returned in an own array^^ Also I used mechanize and nokogiri to extract the text from the page which automaticly deals with the crappy html problems. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Weird. The square brackets don't work for me in irb, and I don't think they should; they define a character class, not a grouped expression.

Comment: `1.9.3p194 :021 > d.content.scan(/([0-9]{1,2}\.\s?(#{months.join("|")})\s?[0-9]{4})/)
 => [["18. Juli 1471", "Juli"], ["11. Februar 1486", "Februar"], ["14. August 1473", "August"], ["18. Juli 1471", "Juli"], ["1. Januar 1501", "Januar"], ["8. Januar 2008", "Januar"], ["23. Mai 2006", "Mai"]]`

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what you *should* get for each expression.